# How to make ContentControl to catch mouse event?

Tags: .net, wpf, user-controls, mouseevent, contentcontrol

If I set width and height of ContentControl it doesn't catch mouse event, for eaxemple mouseleftclick event. Is there a property that to allow me to do it?

```
<Border Width="19" Height="19" BorderBrush="Gray" BorderThickness="1" MouseDown="OnLayerEditedMouseDown">
    <ContentControl Width="19" Height="19">
        <Image                                  
            Width="16"
            Height="16"
            Source="../../Resources/Images/LayersViewer/pencil2.png"
            Visibility="{Binding IsEdited, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
        </Image>
    </ContentControl>
</Border>
```

I can catch events on the Border and Image if it is visible now. The main problem that if a contentcontrol doesn't have any visible content it doesn't catch any event. Can I make a contentcontrol to be a part of visual tree or I must put something in it in any way(for example empty image)?

I've resolved the problem by this solution:

```
<Grid Margin="0">
<Image                                  
    Width="16"
    Height="16"
    Source="../../Resources/Images/LayersViewer/eye.png"
    Visibility="{Binding IsVisible, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}"
    Panel.ZIndex="1"
    >
</Image>
<Image                                  
    Width="16"
    Height="16"
    Source="../../Resources/Images/LayersViewer/empty.png"                                          
    Panel.ZIndex="0"
    >
</Image>
</Grid>
```

It is not what I wanted, but it is better than nothing..

Comment: Please, before set -1 of the question, please make an effort to tell me what a problem is. if you think that it is a stupid question it won't take much time to write the rigth answer, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Hi try this and its working

```
 <ContentControl Width="19" Height="19">
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <Image                                  
                Width="16"
                Height="16"
                Source="../../Resources/Images/LayersViewer/pencil2.png"
                Visibility="{Binding IsEdited, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
            </Image>
        </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: No, I can't to set text as a content. I can show an image or nothing in it. And it is not important where to set mouse handler, because mouse events are routed events, so if you click on a child element, its parent will process it.

Comment: I have updated the solution . When you set e.Handled = true then the event does not bubble up to parent.Don't set the Content set what you want , it was just example.

Comment: I need to use bubbling. I want to catch mouse events of all children of the border element in the border element

Comment: The main problem is if an element doen't show any visible content it doesn't catch any events.

Comment: Try to remove your text from content in your test and try to click on your contentcontrol

Comment: ContentControl do need the Content . If you do not want to show any content then just do it like this Content="". And everything will work.

Comment: I have a content, I have the image in it, but when this image is collapsed, the content become Null, i think.

Comment: Image is child of ContentControl not the Content property value . When you click on image it is the Mouse event of Image control not of ContentControl. To get ContentControl events you need to set Content.

Comment: You are not correct, Image is the child that is put in the Content property of a ContentControl. Content property type is Object. You can set Content property as a string Content = "", or you can set it as a child for complex types. You can't set a child elemtn and content property at the same time, because it is the same property

Comment: I understand that when the image is visible I get events of the image, but when this image is collapsed I don't catch events from contentcontrol itself.

Comment: give your image control a name say(img) and then in codebehind see var a=img.Parent; Yes Content is of Type Object and you can assign UIElement to it but for that you will have to do like i now did above in answer.Now i got your problem . see above i have updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ContentControl Width="200" Height="200" Background="Black" MouseLeftButtonDown="ContentControl_MouseLeftButtonDown">
        <ContentControl.Content>
            <Border  Width="16" Height="16" Background="White">
                <Image                                  
                    Source="../../Resources/Images/LayersViewer/pencil2.png"
                    Visibility="{Binding IsEdited, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
                </Image>
            </Border>
        </ContentControl.Content>
    </ContentControl>
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: it is the same if you write: <ContentControl Width="200" Height="200" Background="Black" MouseLeftButtonDown="ContentControl_MouseLeftButtonDown">
        
            <Border  Width="16" Height="16" Background="White">
                <Image                                  
                    Source="../../Resources/Images/LayersViewer/pencil2.png"
                    Visibility="{Binding IsEdited, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibility}}">
                </Image>
            </Border>
       
    </ContentControl>